# Http Client using JAXRS Client API (POST Request) in Websphere Liberty Profile

Tags: web-services, jax-rs, websphere-liberty, cics

I need to create an Http Client to test a REST web service with JAXRS Client API (lib: javax.ws.rs.client.*) provided by WLP. I'll have to send a String Request (JSON message) using POST method and Receive a String Response (JSON message). I'll be grateful if someone has a similar Java Code (Class) and the necessary imports to do this task.

PS : I started coding the Java Class but I didn't know how to get the response:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(); 
WebTarget myResource = client.target("http://example.com/webapi"); 
....
```

I'm using:

```
Websphere Liberty profile 16.0.0.2, 
jaxrs-2.0 [1.0.0] 
jaxrsClient-2.0 [1.0.0]
IDE : RDz
```

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there. All you need to do is format your request data into an instance of 'Entity' and send it off to your service.

Below is some example code that does this for a very simple JAX-RS service.

```
    import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
    import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
    import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
    import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

    ....

    // Set up our client and target our JAX-RS service
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:9081/example.jaxrs/test/SimpleService");

    // Build our request JSON into an 'Entity'. Replace 'myData' with your JSON
    Entity<String> data = Entity.entity("MyData", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);

    // Then send a post request to the target service
    String result = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(data, String.class);
```

Comment: Hello Michael, thanks for answering but I still have WARNING and errors : [WARNING ] HTTP Response code appears to be corrupted
[WARNING ] Interceptor for {http://9.458.365.147:11491/webservice}WebClient has thrown exception, unwinding now
Could not send Message.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget myResource = client.target("http://example.com/webapi"); 
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = myResource.request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);
Response getResponse = invocationBuilder.get();
if (getResponse != null && getResponse.getStatus() == 200) {
   String responseString = getResponse.readEntity(String.class);
}
```